# springboot RestTemplate post request 401 unauthorized but working from postman

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm able to fire post request successfully from postman, but using springboot RestTemplate i'm getting 401 unuthorized error. please find below my code, i'm not getting where I'm doing wrong

```java
     RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36");
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        headers.add("Accept", "application/json");
        JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("client_id", "h_admin");
        jsonObject.put("client_secret", "*********");
        jsonObject.put("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        jsonObject.put("token_format", "opaque");
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(jsonObject.toString(), headers);
        HttpEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.exchange("https://test.com/oauth/token", HttpMethod.POST,request,Object.class);
        System.out.println(response.toString());
        System.out.println(response.getHeaders());
```

Comment: as you are calling "https" service hope you have installed SSL certificate. Through postman might be it is disable that is why it is working through postman

Comment: I didn't do any SSL Certificate installation, but in postman, SSL is enabled. Even with curl command, I'm able to make a request

Comment: I Tried MultiValueMap one instead of JSONObject it worked, but don't know why JSONObject didn't work